# Problems setting up a local site

Tags: server, apache

I am running into problems with virtual hosts while trying to run Craft locally.
My setup was working perfectly and after a restart of my mac I get error messages and I don't understand why.

I am using Mamp to run Apache and MySQL.
When I am going to one of my virtual host url I get the following error:

[image]

And when I type 'localhost' I get the following:

[image]

I have double checked the **httpd.conf** and the virtual hosts is enabled and my **httpd-vhosts.conf** is set up correctly as well.

I assume there is a certain issue with the virtual hosts as but I just cannot figure it out and it stop working without any changes/updates form my side so I'm really loosing it...

Does any one has an idea where to start searching for the problem?

Comment: Please check if http://ttp.craft.dev/phpmyadmin is working

Comment: Not working. http://localhost/phpmyadmin works

Comment: Then there is an issue with your virtualhost. Please double check it. Or try creating a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the domain .dev anymore, it's Google's gTLD (https://icannwiki.org/.dev) and they don't want to share. See https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd for a detailed backstory.

Instead, you should use [the TLDs reserved by the IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test) for this purpose, like `.test`.

For reference, this is [the HSTS List maintained by Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/hsts) which is in turn the basis for the lists used by [Firefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SecurityEngineering/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_(HSTS)_Preload_List), Opera, Safari, [Internet Explorer and Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3071338/internet-explorer-11-adds-support-for-http-strict-transport-security-s)

Comment: I didn't set up my environment for SSL but for some reason when I type in the browser ttp.craft.dev it gets the https added automatically. Would that might be some hint?

Comment: Please try the solution on this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586593

Comment: @hashtagerrors Not really? Chrome 63 (out since December 2017), forces all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header. This behaviour will be extended to other browsers over the coming weeks. Good luck with continuing to use .dev.

Comment: @hashtagerrors You are also ignoring the fact that this is a legit gTLD that you should not be using for local dev. There are specific domains defined for local dev, this is not one of them. It may have worked in the past, that does not mean it was ever the right thing to do; it wasn't.

Comment: @SethWarburton Yes you are right. I support you on this, that's why I thanked you for the information.

Comment: So my problem was a browser issue as mentioned above. Works still in safari, fire fox and opera (the ones I have tested)

Comment: @LessandMoreCollective It won't work for long in those other browsers, when they are updated they'll include the updated HSTS preload list too, all major browsers use the same Chromium list.

Comment: @SethWarburton I've heard that, but haven't been able to find any documentation/verification of it. Do you happen to have a link or two?

Comment: @BradBell Answer updated with some links :)

Comment: @SethWarburton brilliant... thank you!