# .dev local development

Tags: https, ssl

I'm getting SSL errors when developing using .dev as a domain name. I believe it's because browsers are now automatically forwarding these to HTTPS://.

Any ideas how to get around this with Craft? I can change the extension but Craft requires .dev for local development I believe.

Comment: What setup are you using? MAMP or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems setting up a local site](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23192/problems-setting-up-a-local-site)

Comment: Craft does not require .dev for local development. You can use any “dev-sounding” domain, it does not require the .dev suffix.

Answer (score 4):

This seems missing from the other answers, so I feel the need to emphasize it here...

**Craft does not require .dev for local development.**

Your local URL can be anything you want, Craft does not care. There is no requirement whatsoever on using a `.dev` domain. That being said, it is recommended that you use a ["dev-sounding"](https://craftcms.com/support/license-enforcement#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain) URL, in order to avoid the licensing nag warning. And even if you're getting the warning, it won't have any negative impact on the capabilities your site.

The other answers already address what to do if you *do* use a `.dev` URL, so I won't cover it here. You may also want to read [this helpful answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/23193/45) on a related question.

Answer (score 3):

Yea Google bought .dev a few years back and now chrome forces https on all .dev domains.  I switched to using .test which has been reserved.  So far, so good.

https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/master/valet), the newest version takes care of that. You may either change the domain with `valet domain test`, or better: automatically secure your project it with `valet secure`.

It's very smooth.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how it is able to bypass the chromium engine logics? Or does it contain a custom browser?

Comment: It generates a self-signed certificate for each local domain. Very smooth.